# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException when application/json-patch+json is used as 'Content-Type' header

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

we are using patch operation to support partial update.

```
@ApiOperation(value="Patch (Partial Update) user payment")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<UserPaymentInfo> patchPaymentInfo(@ApiParam(value = "The user id", required = true)@PathVariable final String uid,
                             @ApiParam(value = "Whether to reteurn new payment info back") @RequestParam(name = "includeResponse", defaultValue = "false") final boolean includeResponse,@ApiParam(value = "Description of changes")@RequestBody final String userPaymentInfoPatchJson) {
    UserPaymentInfo paymentInfo = userPaymentService.patchPaymentInfo(uid,userPaymentInfoPatchJson,includeResponse);
    HttpStatus status = includeResponse ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
    return new ResponseEntity<>(paymentInfo,status);
}
```

Below mentioned is exception :

```
    {"code": "0000",
"message": "Could not find acceptable representation (HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException)",
  "host": "localhost",
  "url": "/users/000020800464/paymentinfo/test",
  "method": "PATCH",
  "causes": [
    {
      "code": "0000",
      "message": "Could not find acceptable representation (HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException)"
    }
  ]
}
```

The same endpoint works good for application/json as header value of Content-Type but 'application/json-patch+json' fails.

Does spring boot support patch bcs i am not able to find related header name mentioned in org.springframework.http.MediaType.java